# My AsyncTask starts after my Activity.onStop(), thus throws error because AsyncTask uses GoogleSignAPI

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

Since my `Activity.onStop()` gets called before the `AsyncTask` is finished, the `GooglePlusAPI` get disconnected in `onStop()`. I understand this is how a `AsyncTask` (Thread) should work, but is there any alternatively design I can do, so that I have a guaranteed `GooglePlusAPI` connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you not want the AsyncTask running, call `cancel()` any time, like in `Activity.onStop()`. Also in the AsyncTask's `doInBackground()`, `onPostExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()`, to add `isCancelled()` check before doing anything which my cause problem as activity stopped.

Comment: Ok I do understand what you are trying to say, but this does not help. I DO want the `AyncTask` to execute, it's just because of the `onStop` that I am loosing the `GooglePlusAPI`. What I am asking is that is there any other design I can do so that this does not happens.

Comment: a guaranteed  connection, just mean you will get notify if the connection lost. no such connection that always connected and usable. Internet can not provide such guaranteed underlying connection.